# How to add collations UNICODE_CI/_AI to an old database

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have an old database running on a Firebird 2.5 server, on which is missing the collations UNICODE_AI and UNICODE_CI. Direct selection on meta tables is indicating this.

```sql
select * from RDB$COLLATIONS where rdb$collation_name like 'U%'
```

returns UNICODE, UNICODE_FSS, UTF8 and UCS_BASIC.

How can I add these collation to my current database?

Comment: Did you try a backup and restore of the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a backup restore of the meta table solve the issue.